# How making changes to a third-party solution file.wsp

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I have a third-party solution "file.wsp" that I don’t have the source code for it, I want to make a change to it, how can I tell it to tell me articles and examples? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wsp is a compressed file, you can open it with WinRAR or WinZip.

Into this you have the dll file with the code. Now you need to decompiler, try this soft.https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Reference [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e7873e09-64cd-4b2a-8a7e-c6eeda32926b/how-to-retrieve-the-code-from-sharepoint-wsp?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Thanks, all is well, now I’m looking for options on how to put it back into "wsp"

Comment: @Fox. Check out cabmaker. https://yieldreturnpost.wordpress.com/2016/06/22/free-tool-to-create-cab-file-from-folder/

Comment: @Christoffer thanks, I have already found another solution.